# JBoss BPM suite installation

Tags: jbpm

I am facing some problems while installing jBPM. I have successfully installed EAP and when I tried to install BPM Suite firstly it shows error as

```
 "the port 9999 is already in use, and is required to be open for this installtion".
```

When I still continue installation I got error as

```
 "Advanced configuration command failed: deploy "D:\JBPM\bpms-fuse-travel-agency-integration-demo-master\test3/domain/business-central.war"
--all-server-groups {
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "Path D:\\JBPM\\bpms-fuse-travel-agency-integration-demo-master\\test3\\domain\\business-central.war doesn't exist.",
    "command" => "deploy \"D:\\JBPM\\bpms-fuse-travel-agency-integration-demo-master\\test3/domain/business-central.war\"
--all-server-groups" }"
```

I tried with all the solution available on internet but the problem still persists.

Comment: Avoid all caps titles please.

Comment: I was trying to be nice and letting you know to avoid all caps titles, because they often attract downvotes. I can't answer your question, I just came across it. And everyone is free to answer or not answer as they please here, so keep that in mind. You want free service from us, not the other way around.

Comment: I appreciate your concern and I am sorry if you misunderstood it. I am really looking for the solution on urgent basis, my work has been stuck because of this so might be it sounds different to you.

Comment: @will what is running on port 9999?

Comment: on my system it is java.exe under TCS protocol

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this error- the port is already in use, this means your EAP server is running. To install it first you have to stop your EAP server.
to stop EAP server use command  `Ctrl -c`. Then try install BPM suite. :)